# Is there a way to allow for parallel edges in generating a random igraph network?

Tags: r, igraph

Just as it says in the question. My networks have many parallel edges, for example, one has 18 vertices and 693 edges.

```
LpOTb.dc.rd <- list()
for (x in seq_len(1000L)) {
  LpOTb.dc.rd[[x]] <- erdos.renyi.game(18, 
                                       693,
                                       type = "gnm",
                                       loops = T)
}
```

I would like to make a random network to compare it to, but I keep getting an error message:

```
Error in erdos.renyi.game(18, 693, type = "gnm", loops = T) : 
At games.c:703 : Invalid number (too large) of edges, Invalid value
```

I would prefer not to simplify my networks and account for random edge weights, mostly because there's over 30 of them and I would have to redo all of my metrics for my networks.

Comment: With 18 vertices it is only possible to have 171 edges (including loops) unless you allow multiple edges between a pair of nodes.  I think that the `erdos.renyi.game` code does not permit that.  You could get to 342 non-repeated edges by making the graph directed.

Comment: How do allow multiple edges between a pair of nodes?

Comment: I do not think that the erdos.renyi.game code permits that.

Comment: Is there a different igraph code that might?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate your own random graph with 18 vertices  and 693 edges using `graph_from_data_frame`.  To match your code above,  I made an undirected graph that permitted loops.

```
library(igraph)
Start = sample(18, 693, replace=TRUE)
End   = sample(18, 693, replace=TRUE)
df = data.frame(Start, End)

g = graph_from_data_frame(df, directed=FALSE)
vcount(g)
[1] 18
ecount(g)
[1] 693
```

If you want to generate multiple graphs like this,  you can mimic the code in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39881840/4752675) mentioned in the comments.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
gs <- list()
for (x in seq_len(100L)) {
    Start = sample(18, 693, replace=TRUE)
    End   = sample(18, 693, replace=TRUE)
    df = data.frame(Start, End)
    gs[[x]]= graph_from_data_frame(df, directed=FALSE)
}
```

Comment: This great, thank you! Is there a way to generate a series of them like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880873/how-to-generate-a-series-of-random-networks-in-r) question?

Comment: Do you always want 18 vertices and 693 edges? Or a random number of vertices like in the link?

Comment: I always want 18 vertices and 693 edges